# Sencha - ExtJS - QuickTipManager - Build Failed c2008

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs6

Settings: Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS, MATE 1.12.1
What I've done:

1. Install the Sencha CMD;
2. Download the Sencha ExtJS (trial version 6.5.2.15);
3. Created the folder /home/master/sencha/test;
4. Do 
   `cd /home/master/sencha/test; sencha app init --ext@6.5.2`
   in the terminal;
5. Put next code into app.js:

   ```
   Ext.application({
   name: 'Test',

   requires: [
       'Ext.tip.QuickTipManager'
   ],

   launch: function () {
      Ext.tip.QuickTipManager.init();
   }    
   });
   ```
6. Do `sencha app watch` in the terminal.

What I've got:

```
Sencha Cmd v6.5.2.15
[INF] Processing Build Descriptor : default (development environment)
[INF] Starting server on port : 1841
[INF] Mapping http://localhost:1841/~cmd to /home/scilef/bin/Sencha/Cmd/6.5.2.15...
[INF] Mapping http://localhost:1841/ to /home/scilef/sencha/test...
[INF] Server started at port : 1841
[INF] Application available at http://localhost:1841
[INF] Loading compiler context
[INF] Loading app json manifest...
[ERR] C2008: Requirement had no matching files (Ext.tip.QuickTipManager) -- /home/scilef/sencha/test/app.js:7:150
[ERR] 
[ERR] BUILD FAILED
[ERR] com.sencha.exceptions.ExBuild: Failed to find any files for /home/scilef/sencha/test/app.js::ClassRequire::Ext.tip.QuickTipManager
[ERR]   at or
[ERR] g.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
[ERR] 
[ERR] Total time: 9 seconds

[ERR] /home/scilef/bin/Sencha/Cmd/6.5.2.15/plugin.xml:378: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/scilef/bin/Sencha/Cmd/6.5.2.15/ant/build/app/build-impl.xml:253: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/scilef/bin/Sencha/Cmd/6.5.2.15/ant/build/app/watch-impl.xml:87: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/scilef/bin/Sencha/Cmd/6.5.2.15/ant/build/app/build-impl.xml:387: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/scilef/bin/Sencha/Cmd/6.5.2.15/ant/build/app/init-impl.xml:436: com.sencha.exceptions.ExBuild: Failed to find any files for /home/scilef/sencha/test/app.js::ClassRequire::Ext.tip.QuickTipManager
[ERR] A log is available in the file "/home/scilef/sencha/test/sencha-error-20171113.log"
```

Same errors I've got when tried to require (or use) Ext.form.field.Number, Ext.form.field.Date or Ext.progressBar.

I'm new with ExtJS and I spent all last day to find the way to fix this problem, but haven't any success. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that since ExtJS 6.0.0, there are two toolkits in one bundle, named `classic` and `modern`. Your command creates a so-called ["universal app"](https://www.sencha.com/blog/using-sencha-ext-js-6-to-build-universal-apps/) that supports both toolkits. The `app.js` file is also used for both toolkits; and in the subfolders `classic` and `modern`, there are files that are used for only one toolkit.

Modern toolkit is for modern devices with touch, classic toolkit for classic devices with mouse and keyboard.

[`Ext.tip.QuickTipManager`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.tip.QuickTipManager.html) is only available for the classic toolkit, since tooltips are shown on mouseover - you cannot hover on touch devices. So you have to move all the QuickTipManager code to `classic/Application.js` or whatever javascript files you have in your `classic` folder.